# In Perl when you return a hash from a sub what is the "quick way" to acess a specific value?

Tags: perl, hash

In Perl, it seams, there is no "simple" way to address a hash directly when it is returned from a sub or am I missing something?

I would like something like this.

```
print ( (hash()){One} ); # Not a thing!
```

You can do that whit an array since the values returned constitute a list.

```
print ( (arr())[0] );
```

But for a hash that does not cut it. I have come up with some ways to sort of get this to work.

```
print ( ${{hash()}}{One} );
print ( 0+{hash()}->{One} );
```

But they seem kinda lame. I mean this is hard to read and reference shenanigans seams out of place for such a simple thing.

Here is more code for context.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

### ARRAY
sub arr {
    my @arr = (
        1,
        2,
        3,  
    );
    return @arr;
}

print ( (arr())[0] ); #Output is 1; 

### HASH
sub hash {
    my %hash = (
        One   => 1,
        Two   => 2,
        Three => 3,
    ); 
    return %hash;
}

my %hash = hash();


#print ( (hash()){One} );       # Does not work
print ( $hash{One}  );          # Output is 1
print ( (hash())[0] );          # Output will be One, Two or Three
print ( (hash())[1] );          # Output will be 1, 2, 3
print ( ${{hash()}}{One} );     # Output is 1
print ( 0+{hash()}->{One} );    # Output is 1;
# 0+ because Perl gives syntax error otherwise. Not sure why (Scalar context?) but one mystery at a time.
```

Comment: Subs can't return arrays and hashes, just 0 or more scalars (list context) or a single scalar (scalar context). Similarly, arrays and hashes can't be passed to subs, only 0 or more scalars.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Subroutines do not return hashes, but a list of values. This list can be converted to a hash.

Given a sub that returns an even-sized list, I would use the following expression to access a hash entry:

```perl
+{hash()}->{One}
```

The leading `+` is sometimes necessary to disambiguate a hash reference literal `{...}` from a statement-level block `{...}`<sup>1</sup>. The unary plus is a no-op and just forces expression context, whereas `0+` would convert the value to a number.

<sup>1. Though in this particular instance the ambiguity is due to the [`print(FILEHANDLE LIST)` syntax](https://perldoc.pl/functions/print), where the filehandle can be enclosed in curly braces.</sup>

If you have control over the function attempting to return a hash, it could be worth considering to return a hash reference instead. Your example would then look like:

```perl
sub hashref {
    # alternatively: "return { One => 1, ... };"
    my %hash = (
        One   => 1,
        Two   => 2,
        Three => 3,
    ); 
    return \%hash;
    #      ^-- create a reference to the hash
}

my %hash = hashref()->%*;  # or "%{hashref()}". Note that this makes a copy

print( hashref()->{One} );  # can directly access keys
```

Comment: The advantage of the latter approach is that it avoids having to "flatten" the hash in the sub and building a new hash in the caller.

Answer (score -2):

Following code snippet demonstrates usage of array reference and hash reference.

Advantage of this approach gains tracking when you have to operate big arrays or hashes -- no need to allocate memory for copy, saves CPU cycles.

In some instances an algorithm might require to create copy what can be easily achieved with dereferencing data structure (see example).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

### ARRAY
sub arr {
    my $ref_arr = [
        1,
        2,
        3,  
    ];
    return $ref_arr;
}

my $aref = arr();

say "
Array content:
    \$aref->[0] $aref->[0]
    \$aref->[1] $aref->[1]
    \$aref->[2] $aref->[2]
";

my @array_copy = @$aref;

say "
Array copy content:
    \$array_copy[0] $array_copy[0]
    \$array_copy[1] $array_copy[1]
    \$array_copy[2] $array_copy[2]
";

### HASH
sub hash {
    my $ref_hash = {
        One   => 1,
        Two   => 2,
        Three => 3,
    }; 
    return $ref_hash;
}

my $href = hash();

say "
Hash content:
    \$href->{Three}: $href->{Three}
    \$href->{Two}:   $href->{Two}
    \$href->{One}:   $href->{One}
";

my %hash_copy = %$href;

say "
Hash copy content:
    \$hash_copy{One}:   $hash_copy{One}
    \$hash_copy{Two}:   $hash_copy{Two}
    \$hash_copy{Three}: $hash_copy{Three}
";
```

Output

```
Array content:
        $aref->[0] 1
        $aref->[1] 2
        $aref->[2] 3


Array copy content:
        $array_copy[0] 1
        $array_copy[1] 2
        $array_copy[2] 3


Hash content:
        $href->{Three}: 3
        $href->{Two}:   2
        $href->{One}:   1


Hash copy content:
        $hash_copy{One}:   1
        $hash_copy{Two}:   2
        $hash_copy{Three}: 3
```